# Launching Links in Own created Apps instead of Browser

Tags: android, android-studio

I have one serious question might you have gone through it.
I have seen that when we send the youtube video links to any person then, when someone opens that link, the link is opens the app(youtube app) in case if he/she already installed youtube app on their device or mobile phone.

Now, i have google out such thing to do with our own created application. But, got some massy results. I want to know that What the actual logic or code to apply the Same ?

What the supported thing to do to implement it ?

EDIT :

Done as below  :

```
<application

    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <data
                android:host="zoomvysame.app.link"
                android:scheme="https"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

and using link after app installation : 
https://zoomvysame.app.link

Comment: search about deeplinking in android, you will get it

Comment: Ya, it's right if you still redirecting to the browser then do one thing, paste the link in phone message app and then try to click on the link sometimes it will ask app chooser there you need to select your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking about AppIndexing(Deep Linking).

App indexing allows a user to click on the link from mobile and navigate the user to the app if the app exists in device else navigate him on play store with app listing.

For doing AppIndexing you need to define acceptable URL scheme in launch activity of your application like:-

```
<activity... > 
<intent-filter> 
<data android:host="zoomvysame.app.link" android:scheme="https"/> 
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/> 
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/> 
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/> 
</intent-filter> 
</activity>
```

In above example when you click a link like "https://zoomvysamescreen.app.link" it will launch your application instead of the opening link in the browser.

There is some solution over AppIndexing is provided by [branch](https://branch.io/mobile-search/app-indexing/?bmp=appindex&utm_campaign=BM-AppIndexing&utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=google&utm_term=appindex&gclid=CJq0qpDwk9ICFVWhaAodc24H7w) and [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-indexing/) you can get more details and more control over App indexing using their implementation.

Comment: I have created demo app recently, clicked link, but, browser displaying FILE NOT FOUND.

Comment: Did you simply create the link or added the support from firebase or branch.io

Comment: I just created project in Android Studio with editing in Android Manifest file as suggested by you. run it. installed app in my device. then from chrome tried to load the link. Is it necessary that the app should on play store ?

Comment: Ok for first time paste that link in the message window and then click on it and while creating link make sure it is "https"

Comment: Can you provide me your link which you have created?

Comment: sure sir, https://zoomvysame.app.link note: i just created demo. its not online..

Comment: Are you clicking on that link from PC browser or mobile browser

Comment: mobile browser link

Comment: I am not sure why it is not working on your side are you sure you have done right configuration in manifest

<activity... >
            <intent-filter>
                <data
                    android:host="zoomvysame.app.link"
                    android:scheme="https"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

Comment: I have tried with the above-provided configuration and it is working.

Comment: Sir, Editing question and putting it to my question. pls. check.

Comment: Please refer the above answer with same provided tag under activity. I have made changes with your host name

Answer (score 1):

**It's Deep Linking**

From official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html)

> To enable Google to crawl your app content and allow users to enter
>   your app from search results, you must add intent filters for the
>   relevant activities in your app manifest. These intent filters allow
>   deep linking to the content in any of your activities.

There are so many deep linking providers like [branch.io](https://blog.branch.io/technical-guide-android-deep-linking-uri-schemes/)